# How can I center these overlapping elements?

Tags: html, css, webkit, centering, overlap

The page is [here](http://creativedesigninfluence.com/tests/circle.php). The source is pretty straightforward. I've tried doing this with `absolute` positioning and a few other methods, none of them turn out exactly right.

Comment: will there always be three or can you determine in the backend how many there will be?

Comment: Using absolutes worked. The link includes a working example. Please upvote so I can post again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yXUdN/

I changed these:

```
#title {
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
    z-index:99;
}
#space-link {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:40%;
    left:30%;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#FFF;
    z-index:99;
}
```

To this:

```
#title {
}
#space-link {
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center; /* horizontal center */
    line-height:240px; /* vertical center */
}​
```

You can also use the `display:table` rules to accomplish this, which would be better in the cases where the text spans multiple lines: http://jsfiddle.net/yXUdN/1/

```
.space-button {
    ...
    display:table;
}
#title {
    display:table-row;
}
#space-link {
    ...
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
}​
```

Also, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes instead.

Comment: Cool. Seems a little hack-y but it works. Yeah I just threw the code together to see what colors I wanted, I'd usually use classes.

Btw the 2nd one doesn't center vertically. I like the first method best for this application. Thanks!

Comment: To center vertically, you can use `vertical-align:middle;` on the `table-cell`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for the three elements and apply the following css to it

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -408px; /* half of the total width of the three elements (272 * 3) / 2 */
    margin-top: -136px; /* half of the height of one of the elments 272 / 2 */
}
```